# Running capacitor of a floor scrubbing machine

Tags: capacitor, electrically-conductive

I have a floor scrubbing machine which uses two capacitors - a running capacitor and a starting capacitor.

The starting capacitor got broken and I want to replace it. The rating is 270-324 MFD, 125VAC.

What's the best rating to use if I can't find this same type of capacitor to work with?

Comment: That's probably an odd way do denote 270 to 324 μF - micro-Farad. 300 μF should do fine; where a 125 V specimen failed (check it does get switched off at operating speed), consider using a 165 V one.

Comment: What greybeard said, match the capacitance and feel free to use any higher voltage rating than the original one.